# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished I have this error when I want to open localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mysql2

I am new to Web Development and have started learning Ruby on Rails from Lynda tutorial "Ruby on Rails Essential Training 4".

I got stuck when I was loading page from localhost:3000. I receive the following error every time I open localthost:3000:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

Till this point I have installed all the gems as required in the tutorial and everything worked fine. Can somebody help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Have you given your database credentials in config/database.yml ?

Comment: Yes I have added my password for root user in database.yml file

Comment: I have tried running rake db:create & bundle exec rake db:create command but it also gives me error.

Comment: Could you please show your database.yml, Gemfile

Comment: development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: simple_cms_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: mypasswordhere
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: simple_cms_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: simple_cms_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871233/ruby-activerecordconnectionnotestablished

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871233/ruby-activerecordconnectionnotestablished

Comment: I have used these solutions but still getting the same error. I have installed mysql2 and it is also included into gemfile. I cannot also perform rake db:create or migrate commands. I feel stuck here, please help.

Answer (score -1):

I was following this series too, you shouldn't run into this problem if you install rails 4.2.6.

You'll need to tweak this command to install version 4.2.6 if 5.0.0 comes out.

> gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc

And it installed 4.2.6 on top of 4.0.0. I then deleted the simple_cms site folder and reinstalled it per the video and after editing the database.yml file which will be slightly different from is, I added my MySQL password to this section of the config -

```
  default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: **InsertYourMySQLPWHere**
  host: localhost
```

Start up the rails server and then you should get the welcome page.

Comment: Rails 5.0.0 is _not_ out - only the release candidate is.

Comment: @sevenseacat Thanks, modified the post.